# Apache 2.4 .htaccess using 1GB memory

Tags: .htaccess

I've a virtual-root-server and tried to use .htaccess with Apache2.4.
But I've seen a strange issue.
It works for short time, but it uses all 1GB memory and slows down the whole server.
I've upgraded to 2GB memory, now it does not use all memory, but still slows down the server and uses up to 75% memory. When I turn off the .htaccess it only uses approx. 22% memory and the server responds normal.
It's Debian 10, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4.33.
It is just the basic .htaccess for authentication of specific directory.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

When disabling `AllowOverride All` it works fine.

Comment: This behavior is _not_ normal. There has to be some cause for this.

Comment: What kind of load do you have on that system?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the better solution is, not to use `.htaccess`, but put the information into the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf` file.

Something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/private/>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "dir with password"
   AuthUserFile /home/mydir/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

And the username and password is stored in `.htpasswd`

This seems to work without using more memory than usual.